# perl cpan install Tk - too much disk space required on the root directory

Tags: perl, module, cpan, tk-toolkit

In a Debian Lenny environnement with Perl 5.8, I'm trying to install the Tk module as root using CPAN in command line but this install requires too much disk space on the root directory, despite the modules are not installed on the root partition. So it looks like the compile is using the root directory.

Can I avoid to resize my disk partition to install the Tk module or is there a simple way to run the compile on /usr or another directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tool are you using to manage the install?  By default, most CPAN tools build the module in your home directory.

If you're using the [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?cpan) tool, you can change `build_dir` to something with more disk space available:

```
$ cpan
cpan> o conf build_dir /tmp
cpan> o conf commit
```

If you're using [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?cpanm), I think you'd just change `~/.cpanm/work` to be a symlink to an appropriate directory.

Also, it's generally preferable to build the module as a normal user, and only use root to install it.  You can do this with `cpan` by setting the `make_install_make_command` and `mbuild_install_build_command` config options to something using `sudo` or `su`.  `cpanm` has the `--sudo` option to install using `sudo`, but I don't think it can use `su` instead.

Comment: If he's using the root user to run the cpan client, it will use ~root/.cpan (or .cpanm) for the build directory - this is sometimes in the root partition, not /home.

Comment: Well, by "your home directory" I meant "the home directory of the user running the tool" not "the home directory of the account you normally use".

Comment: thx, it works like a charm. And yes, my fault if I created that confusion: the root user home directory is the root directory partition.